# Use sudo with an EACCESS error when installing firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, npm-install

I tried to install **npm install -g firebase-tools** and I got an "EACCES: Permission denied" error. I have been reading up on a solution and most people say just to write "sudo" in front of the command but I was told said that sudo was bad practice. What is the best solution here?

Comment: sudo is very standard practice.  If you can't install using your user account, then you need to sudo to root account.  Either that, or find a different way to use nodejs without requiring root.

Comment: You should never use `sudo` with `npm`. The NPM repository is full of malware, with dozens of new malicious packages each day. Follow the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally